# Get HTML after JavaScript has been loaded

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

I tried jSoup but it loaded the HTML without loading the script. I want to get the HTML after the script has been loaded.

I tried another method which explained extracting HTML from WebView, but I am doing my work in the background, through a service. So, I cannot use WebView.

Does somebody know how to go about doing this?

Comment: if you import your JS within the head section then I guess, the script loads before your HTML page.

Comment: I am loading a webpage, so I can't control that. Also, in the <body> there are two <script>. That's the only content in <body>.

Comment: How about [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't seem to work in Android Studio. Wasted 5 hours trying to remove different errors. Found someone else having the same problems.